# ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 38: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//

Tags: mysql-error-1064

I am trying to run a mysql script on centos. I have following mysql installed.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                                                |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.25-73.1                                          |
| protocol_version        | 10                                                   |
| slave_type_conversions  |                                                      |
| version                 | 5.6.25-73.1                                          |
| version_comment         | Percona Server (GPL)                                 |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                                               |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                                                |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

My sample script looks like:

```
DELIMITER //



DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_table1_category_insert;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_table1_category_update;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_table1_category_insert 

AFTER INSERT

ON 

table1_category 

FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 
insert   into table1_category_history (
 table1_category_history_id,
 table1_id,
 transaction_start_date 
    ) values (    
    new.table1_category_id,
    new.table1_id,
  new.create_date
 );
END;

//


CREATE TRIGGER trg_table1_category_update AFTER UPDATE on table1_category FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

insert   into table1_category_history (
 table1_category_history_id,
 table1_id,
 transaction_start_date
 ) values (    
    new.table1_category_id,
    new.table1_id,
  new.create_date 
 );
END;

//

DELIMITER ;
```

My database utilizes utf8 encoding. While importing this file in database on mysql client it keeps throwing

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//

CREATE TRIGGER trg_table1_category_update AFTER UPDATE on ta' at line 1
```

I do not see any syntax error while using the delimiter, also **it works on some machines absolutely fine**, i have googled almost 100s of links and tried all the ways with downgrading/upgrading mysql server/client , my.cnf, charset etc it is not helping me out. Can anyone please help me on this? Can there be any settings done at client level to interpret it correctly.I am using the same version client that comes with mysql server installation.

Comment: what tool are you using to run the script?

Comment: Hi, i am using normal mysql shell client to run the script like mysql> source ./myfile.sql